# How to intercept the end of a transform: Rotation operation in QT QML

Tags: c++, qt, rotation, qml

I have the Image of an arrow in my QML file. I would like to rotate it to a specific position. The position is set by a C++ code.
In the C++ code I have a QThread which change the value of the position every 1 ms. In this situation a previous rotation is not ended (i suppose) and in the display i see an "echo" of the previous position.
I would like to avoid the change of the position value, until the previous rotation is over.
For example: If i set the position to 40 and it takes 3 ms to execute the rotation, in the next 3 ms the C++ code doesn't have to change the position.
QML File:

```
Item {
    id: speedo
    property real speedvalue: 20
    property real prevspeedvalue: 20
    property string numero: "000000000";
    property alias tachiText: tachi.text
    x:0
    y:0
    width:1400
    height:540
    Rectangle
    {
        x:0
        y:0
        width:1400
        height:540
        color: "black"
    }
    Image {
        source:"BigDash_images/sfondo.png"
        id:sfondo
        x:0 ; y:0
        width:1400 
        height:540 
    }
    Image {
        source:"BigDash_images/meter_wheel.png"
        id:meter_wheel
        x:430 ; y:13
        width:539 
        height:513 
    }
    Text {
        text:'02478981' 
        font.pixelSize:22
        color:Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 1)
        id:tachi
        x:627 ; y:390
        width:148 
        height:33 
        font.letterSpacing : 5
    }
    Image {
        source:"BigDash_images/indicatore.png"
        id:indicatore
        x:556 ; y:256
        width:192
        height:143
        transform: Rotation {origin.x: 142; origin.y:46; angle:(speedo.speedvalue-20)*1.25}
        smooth: true
    }
    Image {
        source:"BigDash_images/color_adjustments.png"
        id:color_adjustments
        x:0 ; y:0
        width:1 
        height:1 
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));
    QWSDisplay::setTransformation(QTransformedScreen::Rot180, 0);
    QDeclarativeView mainView;
    mainView.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    mainView.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("BigDashboard/BigDash.qml"));
    mainView.setAttribute(Qt::WA_AutoOrientation,true);
    mainView.showFullScreen();
    QObject *object = (QGraphicsObject *)mainView.rootObject();
    Threddi th(object);
    th.start();
    return app->exec();
}
```

Rotation QThread Code:

```
Threddi::Threddi(QObject *pobj)
{
    m_pView = pobj;
    m_pFreccia  = m_pView->findChild<QObject *>("indicatore");
}
#define GRANO ((int)1)
void Threddi::run()
{
    int verso = GRANO;
    int prepos = 20;
    int pos = 20;
    int numero = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        QThread::msleep(1);
        prepos = pos;
        pos+=verso;
        if (pos>=220)
        {
            verso = -GRANO;
            pos+=verso;
        }
        else if (pos<=20)
        {
            verso = GRANO;
            pos+=verso;
        }
        if (m_pView!=NULL)
        {
            m_pView->setProperty("speedvalue",pos);
        }
        else
            printf("m_pView == NULL!!!!!\n\r");
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

**Shubhanga**
I have implemented your suggestion in this way: In the QML File I put a new property named `abilitato`. onAngleChanged put this property at 1. In the C++ code if `abilitato` is 1 then `abilitato = 0` and change pos. The result is the same as before. I think that anglechanged is emitted when the property is changed and not when the rotation is finished.

c++ code snippet:

```
QVariant a = m_pView->property("abilitato");
int val = a.toInt();
if (val == 1)
{
m_pView->setProperty("abilitato",0);
m_pView->setProperty("speedvalue",pos);
}
```

QML File snippet:

```
property real abilitato: 1
transform: Rotation                    
{                                      
origin.x: 142;                     
origin.y:46;                       
angle:(speedo.speedvalue-20)*1.25  
onAngleChanged: speedo.abilitato= 1
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use QML `RotationAnimation` element?
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-rotationanimation.html

Comment: I don't have understand how to set the angle and start rotation from c++

Comment: Do you really need to do the rotation animation from c++? With QML Animation element you can do this directly from qml file. You just have to set your animation in the qml file and remove your thread.

Answer (score 0):

From your code what I learnt is that you are setting the property

`m_pView->setProperty("speedvalue",pos);`

which changes the rotation of the Image. When you are doing this, you don't know whether the previous rotation has ended or not. To make sure that the new value of rotation is applied to the image after previous rotation is completed, the decision has to be taken at QML side. So my idea would be as follows (Please note that I have not tried out your code)

1)When you calculate new rotation value for image in the thread, don't set the `speedvalue` property. Instead store the new `speedvalue`in a queue.

2)In QML side once the rotation of the image is complete, `onAngleChanged:` you can read the next value for `speedValue` from the queue and use it set  the new `angle`. Remember to remove the read value from the queue once you have read it.

Once again, I would like to state that I have not tested the above idea.